# How to Customize Custom Label data in formula field

Tags: apex, community, formula, customlabel

I got a requirement to customize custom label data and display in a formula field.

Like i have custom label called Deal Users and data like.
Robin,Rivera,Jose,opp,Dcosta,James

Now i want to display data like

```
 Robin

 Rivera

 Jose

 opp

 Dcosta

 James
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTITUTE` function to replace the `,` with a line break like below.

```
SUBSTITUTE('Test,Test1,Test2', ',',  BR() )
```

This would display as

```
Test
Test1
Test2
```

Comment: This is correct. Just replace 'Test,Test1,Test2' with  the custom label like this where  `mylabel` is a custom label with value `Robin,Rivera,Jose,opp,Dcosta,James`.  

    `SUBSTITUTE($Label.mylabel, ',', BR())`